# Issues creating an inherited class in Python (recursion error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-class

I'm having some issues creating a basic python module using inherited classes. I keen getting `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Below is a snippet of how I'm wanting my code to work:

```
from foo import Client

x = Client()
y = x.contacts.me()
```

How do I structure my classes to accommodate the syntax above?

Here's what I have in my `__init__.py`:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, access_token=None):
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.base_endpoint = 'https://someapi.com'
        self.contacts = self._contacts()

    def _contacts(self):
        from foo.contacts import Contacts
        self.contacts = Contacts(self)
        return self.contacts
```

And in my `contacts.py`:

```
from foo import Client
import requests


class Contacts(Client):

    def me(self):
        response = requests.get(self.base_endpoint + 'contacts/me', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.access_token})
        return response.json()
```

Comment: How do your classes look at the moment?

Comment: Any chance `Client` depends on `y`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I've updated the question to include the classes I'm working with

Comment: Why does `Contacts` inherit from `Client`? and why are you passing `self` as the `access_token` parameter? That doesn't make much sense... It seems the easiest fix is to not have `Contacts` inherit from `Client`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga because I'm needing to use the `access_token` that's being set in the instance of `Client`.. should this be stored elsewhere?

Comment: I can see that `from foo import Client` near `Contact` definition while `Client` depends on `Contact`. What is the dependance hierachy here?

Comment: That doesn't explain why you are *inheriting* from Client. You could just make `Contacts` take an access token, and initialize it in `Client` something like `self.contacts = Contacts(self.access_token)`. Here's a good rule of thumb: *don't use inheritance.*